# Multilevel expander View in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, telerik, windows-phone-8, expandablelistview

I am developing windows phone application and got stuck in a problem where I need use ExpanderView (using Telerik or phonetoolkit) but at Multiple levels (0-5), much like TreeView.
Please share any tutorial if anybody got one.
I just spent many hours in playing with this control but no luck.

Zauk

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Telerik Examples app in the store? I belive there is an example like the scenario you want.

Comment: No , there isn't[link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/windows-phone-8/general-discussions/treeview.aspx)  . well I achieved this task upto specific level by defining multiple expanderviews inside expanderview and this almost solve my problem.

Comment: I'm wondering how the multiple layers (treeview) would look on the phone. The mail client and others usually expand one layer. I wrote a blog post on using DataBoundListBox with RadExpander that you may be interested in. http://blogs.telerik.com/michaelcrump/posts/13-01-30/windows-phone-8---retrieving-contacts-in-json-format-for-conference-buddy

Comment: Yes I agree  but it was client's requirement according to this we need to show some kind of 

categories -> sub categories -> sub sub categories  etc  in expander view.

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample code provided by Codplex for windows phone-8 and see Expanderview it's very clear and easy to use.